# Экономим память с динамическими массивами от C++

Tags: оптимизация, c++

Здравствуйте, при работе с динамическими массивами приходится выделять память под переменную, чтобы запомнить размер этого массива. Но ведь оператор new[] выделяет из кучи не только память под массив, но непосредственно перед массивом выделяется место под размер этого массива, чтобы delete[] смог выполнить нужное количество деструкторов. Так вот у меня появилась мысль:"а зачем собственно дважды выделять место для сохранения размера массива?"

Как пример, вот такой вот код:

```
class A
{
public:
    ~A(){}//предположим, что некий деструктор определен
};
class B
{
    A* pa;
    //int sz; ведь нам не нужно хранить размер массива
public:
    B(int n) //динамически конструируем массив, получив его размер
    {
        pa=new A[n];
        //sz=n; операция стала лишней - ещё и размер кода сокращается! 
        //мелочь, а приятно
    }
    void go() //проходим по массиву
    {
        //for(int i=0;i<sz;i++); нет, это не наш метод, обойдемся без sz
        for(int i=0;i<*(((int*)pa)-1);i++);//совсем другое дело
    }
    ~B(){delete[] pa;}
};
```

Класс **B** имеет в распоряжении массив объектов класса **A**. Нет необходимости добавлять лишний член класса для сохранения размера, он уже записан оператором new в выделенную из кучи память. 
Если счет объектов **B** идет на тысячи (как например в задаче, которая меня натолкнула на эту мысль), счет сэкономленной памяти идет на **килобайты**!
Что вы об этом думаете?:)

Answer (score 5):

Нельзя закладываться на то, что по смещению -1 лежит размер массива. Кажется это не гарантируется стандартом. Да и килобайты не волнуют никого уже давно.

ЗЫ: по-моему даже в реализации vector из gcc хранится три указателя, на начало, конец и конец выделенной памяти (хотя это не по делу, там malloc-ом память выделяется).

Answer (score 2):

Из пушки по воробьям, по-моему. Позаботьтесь о будущих поколениях - напишите проще.

Answer (score 2):

Полагаться нельзя, и вот почему: когда я перегружал оператор `new`, то заметил интересное поведение компилятора от MS. Если в классе `A` пользователь не определил деструктор, то памяти выделялось ровно столько, сколько нужно для размещения объектов, без "хвостика", в котором записывается кол-во объектов, для которых была выделена память. Предположение очевидно - этот "хвостик" нужен для того, чтобы в `delete` получить адреса всех объектов и вызвать для них деструкторы, а раз пользователь деструктор не определил, стало быть, можно очистить все тривиальным образом и "хвостик" не нужен.
Теперь представьте что пользователь не определил деструктор и по смещению "-1" фактически лежит мусор. Как вариант можно сделать класс `B` шаблонным и проверять есть ли у класса `А` определенный пользователем деструктор или нет, но тогда можно забыть об использовании неPOD-типов.

Понятно, что это уже внутренняя оптимизация, наличие или отсутствие которой не гарантируется в других компиляторах или компиляторах других версий.

Т.ч. лучше, как уже было сказано, делать все "легальным" путем.

Answer (score 1):

К вышесказанному хочу дополнить, что деструктор у класса A будет всегда создан, если не программистом, то компилятором, и это никак не влияет на описанную схему выделения/освобождения памяти.

Comment: В VC++ влияет. Если не определить деструктор явно, то оператор new уже не запишет размер перед выделенным массивом.

Comment: Антон, не может такого быть! Это приводило бы к огромным утечкам, а то и вообще к нарушению доступа к памяти. То, что написано на Си, не имело бы шансов работать (я имею ввиду plain-массивы, разумеется).

Comment: Только что перепроверил: это именно так, при отсутствии явно определенного деструктора, размер массива не записывается. И я не понимаю, как это может повлиять на работоспособность Си кода...

Comment: Какая у вас версия компилятора?

Comment: Откуда утечки, откуда нарушения? То что выделено new[] должно удаляется delete[], как это может пересекаться с Си кодом? Оно не должно быть освобождено, например, с помощью free(). Такое действие в принципе не приведет ни к чему хорошему... память освободится, но деструкторы не исполнятся...

Comment: О free() я не говорю - это и так понятно. Если компилятор при вызове new[] в память где-то не запишет размер выделенного блока памяти, то как потом delete[] сможет правильно ее освободить?

Comment: Задача освобождения лежит на ОС, системе известно сколько памяти было выделено по конкретному адресу, всё что ей нужно для того, чтобы освободить - адрес. А для delete[] это значение нужно, чтобы вызвать определенное количество деструкторов, но если деструктор не определен, то стало быть и вызывать нечего, достаточно простого освобождения памяти по этому адресу.

Comment: компилятор у меня из 2008 студии, "Microsoft® C/C++ Compiler Driver" версия "15.00.21022.08 built by: RTM"